# No longer able to install python packages with pip `ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _socket: %1 is not a valid Win32 application`

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

Using Windows 10

This is a new problem and I am unsure what change caused it. I have always succesfully used pip before. When I try to do a pip install I always receive this exact error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\runpy.py", line 192, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\Scripts\pip.exe\__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\main.py", line 10, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.autocompletion import autocomplete
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\autocompletion.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main_parser import create_main_parser
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\main_parser.py", line 7, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli import cmdoptions
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\cmdoptions.py", line 23, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.progress_bars import BAR_TYPES
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\progress_bars.py", line 12, in <module>
    from pip._internal.utils.logging import get_indentation
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\utils\logging.py", line 9, in <module>
    import logging.handlers
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\logging\handlers.py", line 26, in <module>
    import logging, socket, os, pickle, struct, time, re
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\socket.py", line 49, in <module>
    import _socket
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _socket: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

What is causing this error and how do I fix it?

Comment: Suggestion: install 64 bit Python

Answer (score 0):

[Not enough reputation to comment, but] You're missing a directory from the %PATH% environment variable. You need to add the Python base DLL location to your path variable, but you'll need another person to give you details.

Edit: You're probably missing the `cuda\bin` subdirectory in your %PATH% variable. Google should help you figure out how to resolve that.

Comment: Isn't CUDA a GPU paralell processing library? Why would that be causing the problem?

Answer (score 0):

A similar issue was happening to me on Windows 7. Modifying the PATH variable did not work with me, but the solution below did fix the issue for me.

**Environment**:

Windows 7

PyCharm

**Steps to replicate**:

```
pip --version
```

**Error Produced**:

```
[...]
    import _socket
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _socket: The parameter is incorrect.
```

I provided only a part of my error message that I recall because I did not store the original error message, and I could not get the original error message since I fixed my issue.

**Steps to fix**:

1. Go here
   https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=KB3126587
2. Download Security Update for Windows 7 for x64-based Systems
   (KB3126587)
3. Install this security update
4. Restart OS

**Sources**

https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/4812

https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/4855